# Add X-header with Sendmail (for using milter)

Tags: sendmail, email-headers

I would like to configure `Sendmail` to include custom X-headers with using Milter
(I want to use the free version).

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what you mean by "Milter", as it is an API.  The easiest answer is to just add the X-* header in your app that uses the milter API.  For instance, an app using python-pymilter might use:

```
self.add_header("X-DSpam-Score",'%f' % ds.probability)
```